# Schrödinger's bounty - a bounty that seems to exist and not exist in the same time

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, bounty, stack-overflow-for-teams

I have placed a bounty (50 points) for a question in my Team more than one week ago. I have tried to award it before the expiration time, but received a 503 error (behind the scene, nothing visible in the UI). The expiration did not seem to do anything meaningful.

The question has an accepted answer with score = 1.

The tech support told me that bounties are not supported in Stack Overflow for Teams, but I have managed to issue and award a couple of them before this one.

Now the question behaves as if the bounty partially exists:

1. `Start a bounty` starts now at 100, as if the bounty was awarded
2. The accepted answer has no associated bounty, as if the bounty was not awarded
3. The user targeted by the bounty has not received the points

I am wondering how to prevent this in the future. This is quite important because all internal presentations made to make the tool popular where I work include this feature and I do not wish for my colleagues to waste their points on ghostly bounties.

Not sure if it matters, but all operations were done from a desktop / laptop browser, not from a mobile phone.

---

Tried another bounty and it cannot be awarded (the same 503 error telling me to check the status on Tweeter). So, it seems the last step is broken.

Comment: If bounties are not supported then it should be 100% not support. At best it is an oversight that you can start a bounty.

Comment: @rene - yes, you right. I would hate to see them gone from SO for Teams because they seem to almost work. Personally, I would gladly use them with this small risk instead of not being able to use them at all. As a slowly growing community administrator, I can use them to motivate some colleagues to make high quality contributions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We initially supported bounties on Teams, but then removed the functionality to resolve some outstanding bugs. Your question has been in a limbo state since then. We've resolved the issue regarding in regards to that particular issue. <s>We're currently testing bounties again to bring them back to Teams.</s> They're live now!

Comment: following your response I am trying to start a bounty for a question within Stack Overflow for Teams (Basic Plan), but I cannot see the option (question asked on 18 September, so it is old enough to allow bounties).

Comment: @Alexei I jumped the gun a bit. We fixed the specific issue you were having, and bounties are currently enabled for our internal Team only. We're testing bounties to make sure everything is fixed before we re-release them to all the Teams. It shouldn't be very long.

Comment: good to know. It would also be nice to know why they failed because it was quite a strange experience. Thanks.

Comment: @Alexei Release was sooner than I thought. Can you refresh and try now?

Comment: I have managed to start a new bounty. Thank you.