# When will bounties be available in Stack Overflow for Teams?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounty, stack-overflow-for-teams

A few days ago I have asked about [a strange behavior related to awarding bounties in Stack Overflow for Teams](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388209/schr%C3%B6dingers-bounty-a-bounty-that-seems-to-exist-and-not-exist-in-the-same-ti). It seems that bounties are not fully supported in SO for Teams so the team decides to drop the option of starting a bounty.

However this is a nice feature that it is useful for some teams. Also, already awarded bounties raise questions about what it is about:

[image: offered bounties]

Is there any time frame for reintroducing bounties in Stack Overflow for Teams?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After discovering that the bounty feature wasn't working as expected (e.g. your experiences as shown on the linked question, as well as various reports through our Contact Us system), we hid it to avoid confusion for users. This autumn, over the next two months, we are working on fixing those bugs and expect to bring it back to users shortly around that time.

Answer (score 1):

This question is now obsolete because the Stack Overflow development team has fixed the issue and re-enabled them in the mean time.

[More information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388209/schr%C3%B6dingers-bounty-a-bounty-that-seems-to-exist-and-not-exist-in-the-same-ti).